# Object.class.getMethod("equals", Object.class) doesn't work with BeanShell

Tags: reflection, beanshell

Object.class.getMethod(methodName, Object.class);

is not getting executed by bsh.Interpreter and throwing exceptions

```
    Typed variable declaration : reflection error: bsh.ReflectError: Method getMethod( java.lang.String, java.lang.Class ) not found in class'java.lang.Class'
```

Any idea how to fix this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Java version used 1.6_29. BeanShell 2

Answer (score 1):

Beanshell doesn't support variable parameters, so you need to put it in an array as per older versions of the Java language.

```
Object.class.getMethod("equals", new Class[] { Object.class } );
```